# Find the minimum natural number $n$ so that $131\times n = 123456789\cdots.$

Tags: number-theory

The question is just "Find the minimum natural number $n$ so that $131\times n = 123456789\cdots.$" My first thought was simply just 123456789/131 to get the answer. However, what does that minimum natural number make any difference here? Additionally, dots following the number at the end are really confusing.  I know this might lack sufficient context to get the solution. But really want to discuss here. Any help is welcome! Thank you !

Comment: Is this supposed to be a contest problem, i.e. something solved by hand? Or a problem where a computer is allowed? Using a computer it is easy to find the solution, regardless of how you interpret your problem, as indicated in one of the answers. Note that there are at least two ways to interpret your problem as well, as noted.

Comment: this is actually... a middle school problem a friend asked me today. It isn't supposed to be solved by computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably a deeply number-theoretic approach to this question, but here's a not overly-mathematical solution.

The numbers $123456789...$ are clearly described by tuples of small integers ($n$,$i$) where $n$ is the number of digits and $i$ is the value of the suffix, such that lexicographic ordering of the tuple is identical to the usual order of natural numbers. ie $(0,0) = 123456789$, $(1,0) = 1234567890$, $(1,1) = 1234567891$, $(2,7) = 12345678907$, etc.

So we need to find the smallest such tuple such that the underlying value divides $131$. For the first few $(n,0)\mod 131$ you have (by calculation) $(n,0) = 31,48,87,...$. The value of $(n,i)\mod 131$ is the respective base value of $(n,0)$ plus $i$. The maximum valid value for $i$ for a given $n$ is $0,9,99,...$. The first value of $n$ for which there is a valid value of $i$ such that $(n,0)+i = 0\mod 131$ is clearly $n=2$. By subtraction $i=131-87=44$.

So the smallest such number is $12345678944$.

With the aid of hand-waving and weird diagrams on a blackboard the above answer would be much easier expressed to the point that it is trivial. It's only the limits of notation and brevity that makes it look complex.

Answer (score 1):

$123456789/131$ is not an integer, so that's not the answer.

The dots can stand for any string of digits.
In other words, you want $ 123456789 \times 10^k \le 131 n <   123456790 \times 10^k$ for some nonnegative integer $k$.  For example, $n = 942418237$ is one possible solution, with $k = 3$ and 
$131 n = 123456789047$, but it's not the minimum because there are smaller $n$'s that will work.

Comment: I actually think that the dots should be interpreted as $101112131415\dots$ Or possibly as $99999\dots$ This question is rather unclear.

Comment: Oh thanks, I see what the problem here is now. This is still a tricky problem...

Comment: I think it is not an infinite string of number such as 101112... or 99999... since it makes impossible to find the minimum number n.

Comment: Of course I don't mean an infinite string.  $131 n$ is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{123456789101112131415161718192021}{131} = 942418237413069705459249757191.
$$

So there's that.

Comment: Other solutions are $~103,149,152,$ etc.

Comment: How did you approach that? Programming?

Comment: @TerrenceLiao Yes, I just wrote a tiny piece of GP/PARI code.  Let know if you would like to see the code.

Comment: Not too familiar with that language. But it would be awesome if I can know the algorithm or just see the code (if that writes like other common language which I understand.) I tried to write a piece a code, but it takes too much time :(

Comment: Here is the function I defined: f(n)=s=123456789;for(i=0,n,s=s*100+10+i);return(s)

This gives f(1)=1234567891011, f(2)=1234567891011, etc.  Then just check f(j) mod 131 until you find zero.  Only works up to f(89), but that's all I needed. It's not at all hard to rewrite this function to go beyond f(89). Something like this: g(n)=s=0;for(i=1,n,d=floor(log(i)/log(10)+1);s=s*(10^d)+i);return(s) will do.  Cheers!

Comment: Why couldn't you use f(n) when n goes beyond f(89)? Does g(n) makes the algorithm faster?

Comment: @TerrenceLiao f(n) assumes that at each step you add a two-digit number to the end of s.  Once it's time to add 100, that is no longer correct.  g(n) actually adjusts for the number of digits being appended. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $123456789=131\times 942418\text{ } $  remainder $31$

In the case that you are looking for the minimum when the dots can be any digits, note that with three further digits (therefore $999$ consecutive integers) you can construct a multiple of any positive integer less than $1000$.

If you add one digit you are looking at a remainder between $310$ and $319$. Two digits gives between $3100$ and $3199$, three digits, between $31000$ and $31999$. This defines the search space.

Answer (score 1):

The minmal $k$ is $94241824$ , resulting in $12345678944$